# How to sort alphabetically a custom list defined with tocloft?

Tags: sorting, tocloft

I have defined a "list of definitions" using the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\newcommand{\listdefinitionname}{List of Definitions}
\newlistof{definition}{def}{\listdefinitionname}

\newcommand{\define}[3]{
    \refstepcounter{definition}
    \label{definition:#2}
    \vspace*{2mm}
    \fbox{
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \par\noindent\textbf{Definition \thedefinition.\\\linebreak \textit{#1}} #3
        \end{minipage}
    }    
    \vspace*{2mm}
    \addcontentsline{def}{definition}
    {\hspace{6mm} #1}\par
}

\newcommand{\listofdefinitions}{
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Definitions}
    \listofdefinition
}

\begin{document} 

    \listofdefinitions
    \clearpage


    \blindtext

    \define{Silicon}{silicon}{
        The chemical element of atomic number 14, a non-metal with semiconducting properties, used in making electronic 
        circuits. Pure silicon exists in a shiny dark grey crystalline form and as an amorphous powder.
    }

    \blindtext

    \define{Latex}{latex}{
        A milky fluid found in many plants, such as poppies and spurges, which exudes when the plant is cut and 
        coagulates on exposure to the air. The latex of the rubber tree is the chief source of natural rubber.      
    }

\end{document}
```

### Screenshots:

#### Page 1

[image]

#### Page 2

[image]

After a few discussions with my PhD. Supervisors, it would be more appropriate to be able to sort this list, not by appearance order, but by alphabetical order.

How can I perform such a thing ?

Comment: `tocloft` is meant for creation of ToCs and changing their appearance, but it is not for sorting. You require something like a glossary or a index, which is sorted by default, however. Your macros leaves spurious spaces in the text as well.... and the `\label` must be placed **after** `\refstepcounter`, not before...

Comment: Hum maybe you have some ideas for me to reference something by alphabetical order ?
I am 100% ok to change the functionment of my macros.

Btw. the formating is not stable, it is just a snippet. In my main report, everything look fine.

Comment: btw. thanks for your remark about the label, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tocloft` is meant to edit ToC features, i.e. the appearance, amongst others, but it has no sorting capabilities. Sorting is always a little bit awkward in `TeX` etc., therefore such external programs like `makeindex` exist.

I suggest to define a glossary database, say `def` and add the definitions of the terms there, then use `\define{foo}` in order to display the glossary entry 'foo'. The reason for a new glossary is to prevent mangling with the regular 'main' glossary.

The sorting is done by `makeglossaries` script, for example.

The `contentlike` style is a new glossary style which displays the glossary entries like in a ToC.

Run `pdflatex foo.tex ; makeglossaries foo ; pdflatex foo`, if the document is called `foo.tex`.

Here is the sorted output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[nomain,toc]{glossaries}

\newcounter{definition}

\newglossary{def}{defi}{defo}{List of Definitions}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{silicon}{
  type=def,
  name=Silicon,
  description={%
    The chemical element of atomic number 14, a non-metal with semiconducting properties, used in making electronic 
    circuits. Pure silicon exists in a shiny dark grey crystalline form and as an amorphous powder.
  }
}

\newglossaryentry{latex}{
  type=def,
  name=Latex,
  description={%
    A milky fluid found in many plants, such as poppies and spurges, which exudes when the plant is cut and 
    coagulates on exposure to the air. The latex of the rubber tree is the chief source of natural rubber.      
  }
}




\newcommand{\define}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{definition}
    \label{definition:#1}
    \vspace*{2mm}
    \fbox{%
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
          \par\noindent\textbf{Definition \thedefinition.\\\linebreak \textit{\glsentrytext{#1}}}           
          \glsdesc{#1}%
        \end{minipage}
      }    
    \vspace*{2mm}
    {\hspace{6mm}}\par
}


\newglossarystyle{contentlike}{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
  {\parindent0em}{}
  % have nothing after \begin{theglossary}:
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  % have nothing between glossary groups:
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \textbf{\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}\dotfill{##2}

  }%
}


\newcommand{\listofdefinitions}{%
  \setglossarystyle{contentlike}
  \printglossary[type=def,]
  \clearpage
}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\listofdefinitions


\blindtext

\define{silicon}

\blindtext

\define{latex}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @JonathanDEKHTIAR: You're welcome. Happy TeXing! `glossaries` is a very powerful package (bundle)

Comment: I already have quite a long document with a lot of definitions, using this method would pretty much require me to re-do everything. Is there a way to modify what I already have so that it is sorted? I have a similar code to the person who asked the question.